# SQL Server connection using named pipes

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 from my windows application using vb.net through named pipes.

I did some browsing and I found, to connect through named pipes we just have to mention "Initial Catalog =Test_DB; Data Source = np:Server_Name;integrated security=SSPI;".

But this doesn't connect to the server at all. Is this the right way to connect to sql sererver using named pipes?

Comment: refer http://support.microsoft.com/kb/265808

Answer (score 0):

What error message are you getting when it fails to connect?

I found that when I installed SQL Server 2008 express the named pipes were disabled by default. 
Try opening SQL Server Configuration Manager. Now open SQL Server Network Configuration in left hand pane and click on Protocaols for SQLEXPRESS. In the right hand pane check that Named Pipes are enabled. Restart SQL server for the change to take effect.

Answer (score -2):

Use named pipeline connection like below

```
CONNECTION_NAME = "Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog="CatalogName";Data Source="Production_Server_Name;""
```